# Writing a document in org-mode: is it possible to refer to a code fragment?

Tags: clojure, org-mode

I'm writing a document in org-mode that contains a lot of code fragments, like:

```
#+begin_src clojure
(+ 1 2 3)
#end_src
```

Is it possible to make a reference to such a fragment, so I can say in text: in this `[[frag1][fragment]]` the sum of 1, 2 and 3 is calculated?

Btw, I'm exporting the org document as latex/pdf and html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it helps you:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
;; (ref:some caption1) 
(save-excursion
   (goto-char (point-min))
#+END_SRC

     In block [[(some caption1)]] 

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
;; (ref:some caption2)
(save-excursion
   (goto-char (point-min))
#+END_SRC

     In block [[(some caption2)]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Putting a `#+name: this-is-my-name` line on top of your fragment, you can link to it with `[[this-is-my-name][fragment]]`.

<kbd>C-c C-o</kbd> on the link will jump to the fragment, but I didn't test how it was exported.

Comment: I tried this, but doesn't work when I try C-c C-o. org-mode says: "No match, create this as a new heading?" Maybe I'm using a different version (7.8.11)?

Comment: I tested this in 7.9.3d, and C-c C-o indeed works. Unfortunately in the html and latex export it doesn't.